# How to remove unnecessary spacing and padding inside the Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am having issues in my application where there is unnecessary spacing and padding in my layout. For some reason there as a big gap of space in between each views. Is there another solution to remove or to avoid unnecessary spacing and padding around my layout?

Thanks for your help!

Layout code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorTeal"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:padding="@dimen/title_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vote_average"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/overview_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_thumbnail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/release_date"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19999999" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/release_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_thumbnail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/overview_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.415"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_thumbnail"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.366" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/playbutton"
    android:layout_width="39dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/trailer_title"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.326"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/overview_text"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.305" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trailer_title"
    android:layout_width="93dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TrailersName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Trailers"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[1st layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umeqi.png)

[2nd layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uVuP.png)

Comment: Please check the link, you need the layout something like that?

https://imgur.com/a/39zdu

Comment: @FenilPatel yes i need the layout something like that

Comment: Okay I will post my answer here

Answer (score 0):

The space and padding you are seeing are not because of `ScrollView`, it's because of `Viewgroup`, try to use `LinearLayout` with vertical orienation, it should work just fine

Comment: What if I am using trying to use ConstraintLayout will that make a difference?

Comment: you need to use it correctly, because scroll view will never add padding in between its child

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I had re-write your code and achieve the result as you want.
Please check the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#009587"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Jumaji: Welcome to the Jungle"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMoviePoster"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/release_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivMoviePoster"
                android:text="2017-12-08"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vote_average"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/release_date"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivMoviePoster"
                android:text="6.4"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overview_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ivMoviePoster"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/overview_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trailer_title"
                android:layout_width="93dp"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/view"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Trailer title" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playbutton"
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/trailer_title"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TrailersName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/trailer_title"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/playbutton"
                android:text="Trailers"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Result,**

[image]

Hope it would be help you.